# How to manage Exception Site List for java security settings from command line

Tags: java, security, command-line

I want to be able to add a new site to the **Exception Site List**, is there a possible way to do this **from the command line or via a script**? (automating the adding procedure of "Exceptioned sites")

[Image: Java security tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLUbn.png)

Comment: Thanks for the accept!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/exception_site_list.html) from oracle tells us:

> The location of the exception site list is set in the deployment.user.security.exception.sites property. The default location is /security/exception.sites. See Deployment Configuration Properties for information on properties and property files.

So, in the end, this is "file system based"; and thus it shouldn't be too hard to identify that file; and given the correct permissions be possible to change the content.

In other words: you could create your exceptions file; and ensure and use deployment properties to tell the JVM about that (see [here](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/758952-java-deployment-config-and-adding-exception-sites-across-all-users) for an example).